# How to locate an element which have same name and same atrributes in different tags in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to locate an element which have same name and same attributes in different tags Like

```
 div!
    !--div!   <input />
    !     !     
    !     !---div  <input id=123 class=selenium123>
    !
    !---div  <input id=123 class=selenium123>
```

Comment: Also you should add some code you tired to achieve that.

Comment: an id must be unique

Comment: If it is like this what is Xpath           div!
    !--div!   <input />
    !     !     
    !     !---div  <input id=123 class=selenium123>
    !
    !---div  <input id=123 class=selenium123>

Comment: @Haripriya Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
By.xpath((.//*[@id='123'])[2])
```

the xpath should be in braces. The [2] at the end denotes the index. i.e. [1] will be the first div tag, [2] will be the second div tag.

I have encountered this issue lot of times. This happens in many websites.